# 関数を再帰呼び出しした時の、関数内のクラスのidが同じことについて

Tags: python, python3

python 3.6.4で以下のコードを作成しました。

```
class Number(object):
    list = []
    def extend(self,arg):
        self.list.extend(arg.list)

def multi(arg):
    cls = Number()
    tmp = []

    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    for line in file:
        tmp.append(int(line))
    file.close
    print(tmp)

    file = open('data.txt', 'w')
    file.write('')
    file.close

    for item in tmp:
        cls.extend(multi(item))

    cls.list.append(arg)
    print ('arg:',arg,' cls.list:',cls.list," id of cls:",id(cls))
    return cls

def main():
    ans = multi(5)
    print('ans.list:',ans.list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

そして、data.txtには以下のデータを保存しておきます。

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

このコードへ期待する動作は、
ans.listが[5,4,3,2,1]となっていることでした。
しかし、実際は再帰呼び出しされたclsのidがすべて同じため、
ans.listは期待とは違った値となっています。
なぜclsのidは再帰呼び出しされても同じidのままなのでしょうか。

例えば以下のコードでは、再帰呼び出しされたクラスのidはすべて異なっており、
期待通りの動作をします。

```
class Number(object):
    num = 5

def multi(arg):
    num_cls = Number()
    if arg > 1:
        num_cls.num = arg * multi(arg - 1)
    else:
        num_cls.num = 1
    print ('arg:',arg,' num:',num_cls.num," id of num_cls:",id(num_cls))
    return num_cls.num

def main():
    ans = multi(5)
    print (ans)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

pythonのどの仕様がそうさせているのか、お伺いできればと思います。

Comment: Number.extend() メソッドの `self.list.extend(arg.list)` を `self.list = self.list + arg.list` に、multi 関数の `cls.list.append(arg)` を `cls.list = cls.list + [arg]` に変更すると `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]` になります。新規にリストオブジェクトを作成すると期待通りの結果になりますので、extend（）/append（）メソッドと新規作成の処理の違いに原因がありそうです（循環ループ？）。

Comment: どうやら頂いたコメントのように変更すると、クラス変数ではなくインスタンス変数のlistに代入されるようですね。extendではselfを指定していてもクラス変数に値を追加しているようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythonのidはその変数のライフタイムの間でしかユニークであることを保障されず、今回の場合は初めに呼ばれるmulti(5)以外のmulti(5), multi(4), multi(3), ...がそれぞれ再帰的な呼び出され方ではなく別々のスコープの範囲内となるため、idが再利用されているのではないかと思います。

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id

このコードがおかしな挙動を見せているのは、fileがcloseされていないのと、list変数がNumberクラスの静的変数になってしまっている点によるのではないでしょうか。
該当部分を書き換えたものを以下にあげます。

ただし、この書き方でもファイルから読んだ値以外で、初めの引数であるargの5がリストに追加されるので、ans.listの最終的な出力は[5,4,3,2,1,5]となります。

```
class Number(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def extend(self, arg):
        self.list.extend(arg.list)


def multi(arg):
    cls = Number()
    tmp = []

    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    for line in file:
        tmp.append(int(line))
    file.close()
    print(tmp)

    file = open('data.txt', 'w')
    file.write('')
    file.close()

    file = open('data.txt', 'r')
    for line in file:
        print(line)
    file.close()

    for item in tmp:
        cls.extend(multi(item))

    cls.list.append(arg)
    print('arg:', arg, ' cls.list:', cls.list,
          " id of cls:", id(cls))
    return cls


def main():
    ans = multi(5)
    print('ans.list:', ans.list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: 提示されたコードを動作させると、確かに値が[5,4,3,2,1,5]となることを確認しました。問題は「クラスの静的変数を使用したこと。にも関わらずidの変化だけを追っていたこと」であったということですね。

Answer (score 0):

multiが初回に呼ばれた時、同一のファイルに読み書きしたあとは空のファイルになるのだから、2回目以降にmultiが呼び出された時tmpは空です。ですから次の部分は実行されていないことはお気付きですか？

```
for item in tmp:
    cls.extend(multi(item))
```

2回目以降のmultiの呼び出しでは再帰は起こらないので、最大でも深度1の再帰しか起きていません。オリジナルのコードを実行すると5回同じIDが表示されたあと、最後に1回別のIDが表示されるはずです。つまり再帰した時IDはちゃんと異なっています。

ではなぜ最初の5回は同じIDかというと、`cls = Number()`で作られたインスタンスは`return cls`で関数を抜けたあと消滅します。作っては消えてを繰り返しているわけです。おそらくメモリの再利用がされていて、たまたま同一のidが割り当てられたわけです。新規のメモリの確保はコストがかかるので。

次のようにしてclsのリファレンスを維持するようにすればidは変わります。

```
g = []
def multi(arg):
    # 中略
    g.append(cls)
    return cls
```

もっと簡単な例では次のようにすればidの再利用の現象が確認できます。Test1は同一スコープにあるときは変数名の再拘束が完了して元のオブジェクトへのリファレンスが消えてからidが再利用されていることがわかります。Test2では明示的にリファレンスを消しています。

```
class Number(object):
    pass

print("Test 1")
cls = Number()
print(id(cls))
cls = Number()
print(id(cls))
cls = Number()
print(id(cls))
cls = Number()
print(id(cls))

print("Test 2")
cls = Number()
print(id(cls))
del cls
cls = Number()
print(id(cls))
del cls
cls = Number()
print(id(cls))
del cls
cls = Number()
print(id(cls))
```

出力

```
Test 1
4434900112
4435036176
4434900112
4435036176
Test 2
4434900112
4434900112
4434900112
4434900112
```

delの代わりに`cls = None`としても同じです。リファレンスカウンタを強制的に0にして、ガベージコレクタにメモリの回収を促します。

#### 蛇足

id()はインタープリタの実装依存なのであまり深読みしないほうがいいでしょう。
またクラス変数でリストを初期化するのはバグの原因になりますので、やめた方がいいです。`def func(x=[])`が危険なのと同じです。メモイズのように意図してやる場合もありますが、他人が読んだ時まずわかりません。

```
class Number(object):
    l = []
    i = 123

def main():
    n = Number()
    print("before", n.l, n.i)
    n.l.append('hello')
    n.i = 456
    print("after", n.l, n.i)

main()
main()
```

実行結果

```
before [] 123
after ['hello'] 456
before ['hello'] 123
after ['hello', 'hello'] 456
```

Comment: idについて詳細に説明していただきありがとうございます。再利用され、idがたまたま同じであったということですね。